# Precise the value of a multiple type in an interface in typescript :

Tags: typescript

Here is my code (in typescript 2.3.4) :

```
type TokenType =  "operator" | "doubleQuote" | "identifier" | "(end)";



interface Token {
    type: TokenType;
    value: string;
    pos: number;
}

interface PosTokenOp {
    type: "operator" | TokenType ;
    value: string;
    pos: number;
    left: Token | null;
    right: Token | null;
}
```

So i would like that PostTokenOp type would be just :

```
interface PosTokenOp {
    type: "operator" ;
    value: string;
    pos: number;
    left: Token | null;
    right: Token | null;
}
```

But if i put only "operator" it don't recognize that it's a part of TokenType and i have error in my code.

So i would like to make type of PostTokenOp equal to "operator" and precise that operator is one of the value of TokenType.

If anyone have any idea on how to do that.

Thanks and regards

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't "recognize that it's a part of TokenType"? This works for me in 2.3.3 on the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/): `declare let posTokenOp: PosTokenOp; let token: Token = posTokenOp;` So TypeScript certainly does realize that a `PosTokenOp` is a `Token`.  Also, why can't you just declare `interface PosTokenOps extends Token`?  Could you give more info to let someone reproduce your issue?  I also doubt that you need enums to fix it, despite your accepting that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Typescript 2.4 you can use [String Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html).

e.g.

```
enum TokenType{"operator", "doubleQuote", "identifier", "(end)"}

interface Token {
    type: TokenType;
    value: string;
    pos: number;
}

interface PosTokenOp {
    type: TokenType.operator ;
    value: string;
    pos: number;
    left: Token | null;
    right: Token | null;
}
```

Before 2.4 you can use the normal Enums e.g.

```
enum TokenType { operator, doubleQuote ,identifier , end}

interface Token {
    type: TokenType;
    value: string;
    pos: number;
}

interface PosTokenOp {
    type: TokenType.operator;
}
```

And the usage is like this then

```
 test:PosTokenOp = {
       type: TokenType.operator
    }
 console.log(TokenType[this.test.type]);
```

Comment: @user462794 See the solution for the version below 2.4. But this time you can not use `(end)` - only `end`.